# Upload a file with different filename in sharepoint , adding file as new version

Tags: 2013

How to upload a file to document library as a new version to existing document when uploading with a different filename? Can this be done OOTB or is there any tool which does this or is there any solution which can be implemented ?

Eg : I have ABC.PDF and I send the file to my manager . my manager send it back updating the document and filename `abc_copy.pdf` . Now when I upload I want it to be updated as a new version to `abc.PDF` and not create a new `abc_copy.PDF`.

Comment: Through server object model, you can implement this functionality. In an Item Event Receiver, in the ItemUpdated() event handler, you can  capture spfile, splistitem and update the versions of this file/splistitem.

Comment: Is there some metadata in the file properties that can identify a unique file?